# Production websites font is larger that local version

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Unsure why the file runs locally with the correct font sizings but the hosted version renders fonts that are larger even though inspector tools says the css is still the same

Comment: Same browser, screen, device viewing both environments? How is the font imported/included? File, webfonts, etc? We need a bit more information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. VSCode was serving it with a default 90% zoom.

Comment: You should go ahead and accept your own answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Luan, please provide some more information. Have you also checked your zoom value? (set to 100%) It seems obvious but the amount of times I have different zoom values on different windows of the same browser...